# Condensing jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking to condense the jQuery I have here into a few lines, I know it can be done but I can't seem to get it to work looking at other posts and round the web...

HTML

```
         <h2>Meet The Team</h2>
     <img src="img/1.png" id="team" class="team" />
     <img src="img/1.png" id="team1" class="team" />
     <img src="img/1.png" id="team2" class="team" />
     <img src="img/1.png" id="team3" class="team" />
     <img src="img/1.png" id="team4" class="team" />
     <img src="img/1.png" id="team5" class="team" />

     <div id="teamintro" class="teamintro">
         <h3>Matt</h3>
         <p>personal intro </p>
     </div>

    <div id="teamintro1" class="teamintro">
         <h3>Garrett</h3>
         <p> </p>
    </div>

    <div id="teamintro2" class="teamintro"> 
         <h3>Erik</h3>
         <p> </p>            
    </div>

    <div id="teamintro3" class="teamintro">
         <h3>Matt</h3>
         <p> </p>
    </div>

    <div id="teamintro4" class="teamintro"> 
         <h3>Chi</h3>
         <p> </p>
    </div>

    <div id="teamintro5" class="teamintro"> 
         <h3>Daemon</h3>
         <p> </p>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.teamintro').hide();

        $('#team').hover(function() {
            $('#teamintro').fadeIn(600);
        },
        function(){
            $('#teamintro').hide();
        });

         $('#team1').hover(function() {
                $('#teamintro1').fadeIn(600);
         },
             function(){
                $('#teamintro1').hide();
        });

         $('#team2').hover(function() {
                $('#teamintro2').fadeIn(600);
         },
             function(){
                $('#teamintro2').hide();
        });

         $('#team3').hover(function() {
                $('#teamintro3').fadeIn(600);
         },
             function(){
                $('#teamintro3').hide();
        });

         $('#team4').hover(function() {
                $('#teamintro4').fadeIn(600);
         },
             function(){
                $('#teamintro4').hide();
        });

         $('#team5').hover(function() {
                $('#teamintro5').fadeIn(600);
         },
             function(){
                $('#teamintro5').hide();
        });

    });


 </script>
```

So what I am looking to do it to get the persons info to appear when you hover over the image of the said person.

Comment: a for loop would work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery passes the DOM element on which the event occurred to your function as `this`, so you can easily get its `id` and use that:

```
$('.team').hover(
    function() {
        var num = this.id.substring(4); // Remove the "team" prefix
        $('#teamintro' + num).fadeIn(600);
    },
    function(){
        var num = this.id.substring(4); // Remove the "team" prefix
        $('#teamintro' + num).hide();
    }
);
```

The selector `.team` matches all of your elements with the `team` class. Within the callbacks, `this` is the DOM element, so `this.id` is its `id`. `.substring(4)` removes the `team` prefix.

Comment: Note that not only do the elements hovered start with `team`, but so does just about every other element

Comment: They do have classes though ?

Comment: @adeneo: And there I go using `filter`. Thanks. Really must walk away from the computer now. :-)

Comment: It's still the right idea, the OP just has a very limited imagination when it comes to ID's. +1 btw.

Comment: Cheers Guys, all working divine. I like my limited id imagination :)

Comment: @adeneo: Even so, I *really* appreciate the comments helping me fix a bonehead answer. It's people like you whom I consider colleagues, despite never having met or even spoken properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thank you, and the same goes for you as well.